# Single word denoting 'I identified and prevented the loss of crude material' for appraisal

Tags: single-word-requests

My cousin is going to submit an appraisal form for his performance for the past 1 year in a petrochemical manufacturing plant.
How to write 'I identified and prevented the loss of crude materials from going along with waste water' in a single word or something short, but describing the effort.

Comment: You've put some effort into fabricating the sentence that shows the effort you've put into your work. Shortening the sentence will sound modest. For example : I minimized losses. But such a sentence wouldn't stress enough on the particulars of the efforts you have put in. It could just be seen as a regular statement. There is no single word for it.

Comment: Would 'I took measures to capture crude material from the effluent' work in your sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say *identified*, since *prevented* is the key word.  However, you could build up the achievement by saying you **prevented** loss of crude materials **by identifying** their presence and alerting..."